# Elasticsearch refuses connection to python Django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a Django project with a model:

```
class ParentFoodDirectory(TimeStampedModel):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=False, blank=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)
    p_id = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Parent Food Items"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This model has more than 10 million objects. The searching on this gets really slow that's why I decided to use elastic search. I set up Elasticsearch on a different instance and used ngnix on the machine. Now the elastic search was available through the ext IP.  Then in order to map this mode on elastic search I made a dcouments.py file:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document, fields
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from .models import ParentFoodDirectory

@registry.register_document
class ParentFoodDirectoryDocument(Document):
    name = fields.TextField()
    active = fields.BooleanField()
    p_id = fields.IntegerField()

    class Index:
        name = 'parentfooddirectory'

    class Django:
        model = ParentFoodDirectory
```

I mentioned the host in my settings:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOST = 'http://35.141.96.246/'
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': '35.141.96.246',
    },
}
```

I get the following error while rebuilding using the command
`python manage.py search_index --rebuild`:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f49febf8d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused) caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f49febf8d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Any clue on what might be happening. The elastic search is reachable. The firewall rules seem to be inplace as well

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr

Default http call are done on port `80` and `443` for https.

By default elastic bind to the port `9200`.

## Solution

Check that elastic api port is indeed 9200.

Update the config of your app to query the right port.